# SQL PHP Get data based on url page name even if data in table does not contain hyphen

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include_once "config/config.php"; ?>
<?php  include_once"libraries/Database.php"; ?>
<?php  $database =  new Database();
$filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$data  = explode(".",$filename);
$town_result = $database->getData("select * from nationwide where town 
= '$data[0]' ");
$area = $town_result->fetch_assoc();
//var_dump($town);
?>
```

I have a page called houghton-regis.php which uses the code above to pull the data from the database to display the following **Houghton Regis** anywhere on the page where there is a tag like this

```
<?php  echo $area["town"];?>
```

The problem is because the data in the table does not contain a hyphen it cant grab it.

Is there a way to get the data no matter what characters it has in the url page just as long as the names match ?

This is an old project I have just come back to so a bit rusty...

Comment: Replace - with a space in the php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replce `-` with `space` in php.

```
<?php include 'includes/header.php';?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include_once "config/config.php"; ?>
<?php  include_once"libraries/Database.php"; ?>
<?php  $database =  new Database();
$filename = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$data  = explode(".",$filename);
$data[0] = str_replace("-"," ",$data[0]);
$town_result = $database->getData("select * from nationwide where town 
= '$data[0]' ");
$area = $town_result->fetch_assoc();
//var_dump($town);
?>
```